# PHP regex preg_match_all for string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

**keyword|title|http://example.com/**

I would like to use the PHP function

```
preg_match_all ( $anchor, $key, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) )
```

currently

```
$anchor='/([\w\W]*?)\|([\w\W]*)/';
```

and I get $matches array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword|title|http://example.com/
            [1] => keyword
            [2] => title|http://example.com/
        )

)
```

I would like to get

```
matches[1]=keyword
matches[2]=title
matches[3]=http://example.com
```

How would I have to modify $anchor to achieve this?

Comment: You just need to add one more `\|([\w\W]*?)` in your regex.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Final expression: $anchor='/([\w\W]*?)\|([\w\W]*?)\|([\w\W]*)/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using the regex to avoid a manual loop, then I'd recommend this over the used `[\w\W]*` syntax and for readability:

```
$anchor = '/([^|]*) \| ([^|]*) \| ([^\s|]+)/x';
```

It's a bit more robust with explicit negated character classes. (I assume neither title nor url can contain `|` here.)

Comment: Hey mario, thank you, this worked. I know nothing about the regex expressions; they look like gibberish to me. Where could i find the rules and mechanics of these expressions? Thank you

Comment: Yes. They are sort of a programming language of their own. It takes time to get accustomed to them. http://regular-expressions.info/ provides a mostly understandable introduction. And here are some tools that can sometimes help in constructing regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be  to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead of regular expressions:

```
$parts = explode('|', $str);
```

Assuming none of the parts can contain `|`. But if they could, regex wouldn't help you much either.

Comment: Absolutely. Just for the sake of it... heres a regex that would work: `/([^|]+)/`

Comment: Gary, this is matches if I use this regex: <pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword
            [1] => keyword
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
            [1] => title
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://example.com/
            [1] => http://example.com/
        )

)
</pre>